# Limits of static method references in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, method-reference

I'm trying to use method references to capture method invocations and am hitting some limitations. This works fine:

```
<T> void capture(Function<T, ?> in) {
}

private interface Foo {
  String getBar();
} 

capture(Foo::getBar);
```

But if I change the signature of Foo.setBar to something like this:

```
private interface Foo {
  void setBar(String bar);
}

capture(Foo::setBar);
```

I get an error:

`Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method setBar(String) from the type MyTest.Foo`

It's not clear to me what the restriction is. Ideally I'd like to use method references to capture invocations on standard setter. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Is this even Java? Or is that syntax new in Java 8?

Comment: Could you please post an error?

Comment: @AnubianNoob This is indeed Java8s method references etc...

Comment: @AnubianNoob that's Java 8, guy. Enjoy it!

Comment: dayum... I've not done much Java 8, this looks painfully interesting...

Comment: Erm, what is "static" about that? I don't see a `static` modifier?

Comment: @meriton: The method reference is effectively static, because it's like a lambda expression which takes a `Foo` and calls a method *on* that reference.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are two problems here:

- You're using `Function`, which has to return something. `setBar` doesn't return anything.
- `Function` only takes a single input, but you've got *two* inputs: the `Foo` you'd call `setBar` on, and the `String` argument you'd pass into `setBar`.

If you change to use `BiConsumer` instead (which has a `void` return type and two inputs) it works fine:

```
static <T, U> void capture(BiConsumer<T, U> in) {
}
```

You can overload your `capture` method to have both signatures:

```
static <T, U> void capture(BiConsumer<T, U> in) { }
static <T> void capture(Function<T, ?> in) { }
```

and then use both method references:

```
capture(Foo::setBar);
capture(Foo::getBar);
```

Comment: Amazingly quick response. Thanks! Once SO allows me I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @JoshStone: Glad it makes sense. I haven't done much with the Java 8 stuff or written about it, so it'll take a while to hone how to explain things. Let me know if there's anything you'd like me to expand on.

Comment: @JoshStone You'll want to keep in mind though that offering all possible overloads (especially once you hit similar arity) will get you into trouble due to erased generics on runtime. Currently I believe there are even some issues with similar arity when `void` is involved, I think a fix for that particular issue is in the works though.

Answer (score 8):

`Foo::getBar` corresponds to a function that takes a `Foo` (the target object) and returns a `String`. The interface `Function<Foo, String>` can be used to represent such a function.

On the other hand, `Foo::setBar` corresponds to a function that takes two arguments, a `Foo` (the target object) and a `String` (the first parameter). The matching interface is `BiConsumer<Foo, String>`. That means you need an overload for `BiConsumer`:

```
<T, U> void capture(BiConsumer<T, U> setter) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Expose syntax sugar method reference, you should see, that

```
Foo::getBar
```

is equal to

```
(Foo)foo -> foo.getBar()
```

which is `Function <Foo, String>`

But

```
Foo::setBar
```

is in this context the function of two variables (`foo` and some `String str`), so it is not the function of one variable (`Function`)

For the more convenient answer you should see, where the [method references](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) are allowed:

1. Reference to a static method (not this case at all)
2. Reference to an instance method of a particular object (not this case at all)
3. Reference to an instance method of an arbitrary object of a particular type (this case)

   In the instruction above there is an example, which is almost the same as in your case. And it is said, that the equivalent lambda expression would be taking **two** parameters (in this case `Foo` and `String`), which is not `Function`
4. Reference to a constructor (not this case at all)